# Is it good coding practice to throw in catch block?

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm doing some service related operation. is the below snippet valid?

```
try {
          //some code here
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
                throw new ServiceException("Error!!!");
   }
```

I'm catching ServiceException and throwing the same exception.
Is it good practice ???

Comment: It's fine practice to throw in the catch block. It's questionable practice to do so ignoring the original exception.

Comment: "I'm catching ServiceException and throwing the same exception." You're throwing the same *type* of exception, not the same exception.

Comment: I see a warning Throw inside a Catch can ignores catch exception in intellj

Comment: Catching an exception and throwing the same again in that block is not a good practice, rather you should change it to some custom exception or do some other operation

Comment: @srp321 "Catching an exception and throwing the same again in that block is not a good practice" sometimes you need to do some cleanup in the catch block, and then rethrow the causing exception. This is completely OK: you don't need to change anything about the original exception, you are just doing something as it whizzes past.

Comment: your sample is sure not good - no reason to create a new exception of the same type without any additional information - it is actually hiding important information (where the exception raised, message). Would be OK if you add some information (e.g. file name, line number, ...) and eventually change the exception type. Also, when doing that, always include the old exception as `cause` to the new one - see method `initCause()` of `Throwable`

Comment: @Andy Turner, i agree with ur point, but then i have an option of using finally as well to do those clean up

Comment: @srp321 that's only if you want to clean up on both success and failure. If you only want to clean up on failure, it has to be in the catch block.

Answer (score 2):

In catch part you actually catch main exception that occurred during code..and then you throw custom/ user readable exception from that..This is good practice.

Comment: For developer point of view,you can print stack trace but do u advice him to pass actual exception to end user?? For example, if there is Nullpointer exception then do u directly show this error in frond side directly?? Or you will throw some meaning ful and readble error?

Answer (score 0):

not good practice. because it is hard to find origin reason for the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow...https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You are not sure whether what you've written is good or bad. In this situation I would document myself a bit about the tools I plan to use, in this case the Exception mechanism from Java and then I would **start asking questions**:

1. Is there a reason why I should catch *ServiceException e* and then throw another one of the same type with less info in it. You created the new one with less information. String *"Error!!!"* is definitely less than what you can probably get from the original *e.getMessage()* or *e.getCause* etc (assuming *ServiceException e* is maybe wrapping another low level exception, document yourself a bit about Exception wrapping).
2. Will some calling code catch a *ServiceException* and act on it? Check a bit your call hierarchy and find the place where you have to act on *ServiceException*. Stop there and **start asking again**. Does it make any difference if here I catch a *ServiceException* with *"Error!!!"* in it or the original *ServiceException e*.
3. I am throwing and catching Exceptions in my code, do I have to somehow track later what happened here? If yes then I would also log some errors, warnings or infos about what happened, depending on the scenario. This way you will make the troubleshooting process easier for someone who's inspecting later the logs of your application. I would also read a bit about swallowing exceptions and why it is bad to do it.